# cardano-cli verification key bech32 encoding

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli

In the `cardano-cli` tool,

it is possible to accept both `--payment-verification-key-file` and `--payment-verification-key` when running `cardano-cli address key-hash`
From the docs, it seems that the `--payment-verification-key` is supposed to be bech32 encoded.

But it is unclear how that is achieved.

How can I convert from the key-file to the key-string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some experiments, the answer is to

Remove the first 2 bytes (5820) from the cborhex and pipe the output to bech32 with addr_vk

For example

```
$ cat vkey
{
    "type": "PaymentVerificationKeyShelley_ed25519",
    "description": "Payment Verification Key",
    "cborHex": "5820ba6e94a603da493604a0e0d0e8c4f3465ba299a0d0967a1cafd4c0fa0ab882ad"
}

$ echo "ba6e94a603da493604a0e0d0e8c4f3465ba299a0d0967a1cafd4c0fa0ab882ad" | bech32 addr_vk > vkeystring

$ cardano-cli address key-hash --payment-verification-key $(cat vkeystring)
$ cardano-cli address key-hash --payment-verification-key-file vkey
```

Both key-hash should be the same.

Comment: thank you for the answer! What are the first 2 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

As Alan has already answered this for himself I'd like to add that when using an extended verification key you can produce the non-extended key first and then bech32 encode it to produce the hash.

For example, produce non-extended verification key from extended one:

```
$ cat acct.vkey
  {
      "type": "PaymentExtendedVerificationKeyShelley_ed25519_bip32",
      "description": "Payment Verification Key",
      "cborHex": "58406d2d6c3e1bf46cfab0977279105a87bb89adb4c6dac3eb25ea2f300ef3e9aa0af720099909a8f7a871db0cb1b2158549cedd2019d60d7ac6c4891bf03cfdc652"
  }
$ cardano-cli key non-extended-key --extended-verification-key-file acct.vkey --verification-key-file acct_short.vkey
$ cat acct_short.vkey
  {
      "type": "PaymentVerificationKeyShelley_ed25519",
      "description": "",
      "cborHex": "58206d2d6c3e1bf46cfab0977279105a87bb89adb4c6dac3eb25ea2f300ef3e9aa0a"
  }
```

Remove first 2 bytes from non-extended key and produce valid encoded address (bech32 binary is included in [wallet release bundle](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/releases)):

```
$ echo "6d2d6c3e1bf46cfab0977279105a87bb89adb4c6dac3eb25ea2f300ef3e9aa0a" | bech32 addr_vk
  addr_vk1d5kkc0sm73k04vyhwfu3qk58hwy6mdxxmtp7kf029ucqaulf4g9q8d6yzn
```

Produce key hashes and compare:

```
$ cardano-cli address key-hash --payment-verification-key addr_vk1d5kkc0sm73k04vyhwfu3qk58hwy6mdxxmtp7kf029ucqaulf4g9q8d6yzn
ad2704179252c6343d8e27708b725656ec30bc8a347dbb42bfd5509a
$ cardano-cli address key-hash --payment-verification-key-file acct.vkey 
ad2704179252c6343d8e27708b725656ec30bc8a347dbb42bfd5509a
```